# SMSGATEWAY.ME - How to use the PHP API?

Tags: php, android, api, sms, gateway

I would like to use an SMS Gateway PHP API but I don't success to use it. I downloaded on my phone with android the software from SMSGATEWAY.ME and I created an account.I have also a free web server and I uploaded on it two documents :

their PHP API Library "smsGateway.php" that peoples can find here :
https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-libraries/sms-gateway-me-php.zip

my file "test.php" :

```
<?php
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('my_email_on_their_website', 'my_password_for_this_account');

$deviceID = 111111; //the number of my device, displayed on their website or on the software installed on my phone
$number = '+1234567891'; //the number I want to SMS
$message = 'Hello World!'; //my message

$options = [
    'send_at' => strtotime('+10 minutes'), // Send the message in 10 minutes
    'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the message is not yet sent
];

//Please note options is no required and can be left out
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
?>
```

But when I visit with my browser http://mywwebsite.com/test.php, it doesn't send SMS, do you know why please ? Can you help me to fix this problem please ? (the gateway on my phone is still active).

Thank you in advance !

Best regards

Comment: Could you provide `$result` value?

Comment: When I add "echo $result" on the last line of my programm and I test it, It displays on the screen :"Fatal error: Class 'msGateway' not found in /srv/disk13/2087179/www/mywebsite.com/test.php on line 6"

Comment: Make sure that `smsGateway.php` file is in directory with `test.php`

Comment: Hi and thank you ! I found finally my mistake : I forgot a "s" to "smsGateway" on the second line. But now "$result" displays just "Array" (a word on my browser). How can read the content of this array please ? Or how can I check if the message has been sent please ?

Comment: using [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). You can add it inside tag `<pre></pre>` for more readable format.

Comment: Thanks, I put var_dump($result) instead of "echo $result" and it displays me that now : array(2) { ["response"]=> bool(false) ["status"]=> int(0) }

Comment: What does it mean in my case please ?

Comment: That mean response wasn't correct. Please check your credentials and check again

Comment: I don't understand what is a credential actually, what is it please ? If you mean the official documentation, I read it again but I didn't find anything new. Here is the documentation about the send of SMS (it's very short) : https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messages/send-message-to-number

Comment: Check values of: my_email_on_their_website, my_password_for_this_account, deviceID. You should get response with success or failure.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by checking these values ? These values are right on their website, I mean, I can connect onto my account with my browser. But do you mean that I have to test these values with some requests in the source code (of test.php)? If yes, which one please ?

Comment: Your response (that you posted earlier) are not similar to these in docs. So you have something incorrect :)

Comment: I posted the code of my test.php file but I didn't write the correct values (for protecting my privacy and not permitting anyone to connect on my account) and so, the "$deviceID", "my_email_on_their_website", and "my_password_for_this_account" are not the same in the test.php file on my webserver and this one on stackoverflow. On my webserver, my email, password and DeviceID match normally, I don't think my problem is due to this. Is it what you meant ? Have you other ideas please ?

Comment: Up ! Sorry if I explain bad my problem, and thank you walkingRed for your help ! Moreover, if you don't have any ideas how to help me in this circumstance, no problems ;) , write it, it will help me, I will try to find other peoples to help me.

Comment: UP ! Has anyone an idea please ? ( Even it's just to answer anything in relation with my first post ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. If you want to display the result write the following line after `$result` variable

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

So your code will look like this

```
    <?php
    include "smsGateway.php";
    $smsGateway = new SmsGateway('my_email_on_their_website', 'my_password_for_this_account');

    $deviceID = 111111; //the number of my device, displayed on their website or on the software installed on my phone
    $number = '+1234567891'; //the number I want to SMS
    $message = 'Hello World!'; //my message

    $options = [
        'send_at' => strtotime('+10 minutes'), // Send the message in 10 minutes
        'expires_at' => strtotime('+1 hour') // Cancel the message in 1 hour if the message is not yet sent
    ];

    //Please note options is no required and can be left out
    $result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
echo json_encode($result);
    ?>
```